# The probability that P satisfies the equation (x-$2$) . (x-$5$) . (x-$47$) . (x-$7$)=$0$ with the following conditions?

Tags: probability

> A number P is chosen from 1,3,5,...47.The probability that p satisfies the equation (x-$2$) . (x-$5$) .  (x-$47$) . (x-$7$)=$0$ is

Options: $1$) $1$/$8$ $2$) $1$/$6$ $3$) $1$/$5$ $4$) $1$/$3$

My approach:

To satisfy the equation I can choose any $24$ nos for (x-$2$).Any one number for (x-$5$)  (x-$47$)  (x-$7$)(taking them as separate cases).

Case1

24 . 1 . 24 . 24/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24) + 24 . 24 . 1 . 24/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24) + 24 . 24 . 24 . 1/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24)

Also There can be 2 zeros

Case 2

24 . 1 . 1 .24/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24) + 24 . 1 . 24 .1/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24) + 24 . 24. 1 .1/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24)

Case 3

24 . 1 . 1 .1/(24 . 24 . 24 . 24)

Adding all the 3 cases

> I am getting a very long Answer :P?Can Anyone give me the hint how to solve this problem or what went wrong.

Comment: Not following your calculation.  Unless I am misreading, you want to know the probability of choosing one of $\{5,7,47\}$ out of $24$ cases.  No?

Comment: @lulu also $2$ is a solution.

Comment: I don't quite understand your approach... Since you just choice one number and only 2, 5, 7, 47 satisfy the equation, isn't the answer comes quite straightforwardly?

Comment: @drhab  OP can only choose odd numbers, no?

Comment: You have three cases in which you get a solution of the equation: $5,7$ and $47.$ Thus, the answer is $3/24=1/8,$ isn't it?

Comment: @mfl Always give the hint like Graham sir give.:) Thankx anyways

Comment: What I did was very funny.I think i was calculating so much combinations.

Comment: @lulu You are right. I overlooked that. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To satisfy the equation I can choose any 24  nos for $(x-2)$. Any one number for $(x-5) (x-47 ) (x-7 )$ (taking them as separate cases).

What are you talking about?

The equation is: $(x-2)  (x-5 ) (x-47 ) (x-7 )=0 $

The roots to this equation are $2, 5, 47, 7$

What is the probability that you select one of these four numbers from the odd numbers between 1 and 47 inclusive?

Comment: Uh, I didn't mean combination... And since you adjusted your answer, I've deleted my former comment.